# Play Protect Submission

Tags: android, google-play-services

I just filled submission form for google play protect for my new-developed game. the problem is with URL download link. I used file.io to generate a direct download link. it worked fine for the first time but now error 404 for "*not found*" is shown. I re-submit a new form with same information but different URL to download my APK (I used DropBox to generate direct link and bit.ly for shortening the link) but google told me via email that it doesn't need to re-submit. I know that the the process for accepting my game could last for 7-10 days. what do you suggest?